# Newtonsoft.json SelectToken Replace differs from SelectTokens Replace in foreach with a NullReferenceException

Tags: json, json.net

Hope anybody could guide me here. I spend some hours on it and can't understand what's going on.

Mission: Replace a json element by a jsonpath search tag. (sort of $ref feature)
In my code example below i want to replace the value of DataReaderUser by a value found by the json path search $.UsersAndGroups.Users[?(@.Name == 'OMDASAccountUser')].Username . In this case it should result in the value "contoso\SVCSCOM-DO-OMDAS"

The code below works as expected.. the issue is below this code ..

https://dotnetfiddle.net/gEjggK

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"{
   ""SQLServer"":  {
   ""SQLReportingServices"": {
    ""AccountSettings"": {
        ""DataReaderUser"": {""$JsonPath"": ""$.UsersAndGroups.Users[?(@.Name == 'OMDASAccountUser')].Username""},
    }
   }
  },
    ""UsersAndGroups"":  {
        ""Users"":  [
                      {
                          ""Name"":  ""OMActionAccountUser"",
                          ""Username"":  ""contoso\\SVCSCOM-DO-OMDAS"",
                      },
                      {
                          ""Name"":  ""OMDASAccountUser"",
                          ""Username"":  ""contoso\\SVCSCOM-DO-OMDAS"",
                      }
                  ]
               }
}";
        
        JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
        
        var JsonPath = jo.SelectToken("..$JsonPath");
        JsonPath.Parent.Parent.Replace(jo.SelectToken(JsonPath.ToString()));

        Console.WriteLine(jo.ToString());
    }
}
```

The output will be :

```
{
  "SQLServer": {
    "SQLReportingServices": {
      "AccountSettings": {
        "DataReaderUser": "contoso\\SVCSCOM-DO-OMDAS"
      }
    }
  },
  "UsersAndGroups": {
    "Users": [
      {
        "Name": "OMActionAccountUser",
        "Username": "contoso\\SVCSCOM-DO-OMDAS"
      },
      {
        "Name": "OMDASAccountUser",
        "Username": "contoso\\SVCSCOM-DO-OMDAS"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now the issue:

I want to do the same for all possible jsonpaths refers. So i use the SelectTokens and an foreach . But it looks like the behavior is different , the parents are null.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/lZW3XP

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"{
   ""SQLServer"":  {
   ""SQLReportingServices"": {
    ""AccountSettings"": {
        ""DataReaderUser"": {""$JsonPath"": ""$.UsersAndGroups.Users[?(@.Name == 'OMDASAccountUser')].Username""},
    }
   }
  },
    ""UsersAndGroups"":  {
        ""Users"":  [
                      {
                          ""Name"":  ""OMActionAccountUser"",
                          ""Username"":  ""contoso\\SVCSCOM-DO-OMDAS"",
                      },
                      {
                          ""Name"":  ""OMDASAccountUser"",
                          ""Username"":  ""contoso\\SVCSCOM-DO-OMDAS"",
                      }
                  ]
               }
}";
        
        JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
        
        var JsonPaths = jo.SelectTokens("..$JsonPath");
        foreach (var JsonPath in JsonPaths )
        {
           JsonPath.Parent.Parent.Replace(jo.SelectToken(JsonPath.ToString()));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(jo.ToString());
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
Run-time exception (line 34): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack Trace:

[System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JsonPath.PathFilter.GetNextScanValue(JToken originalParent, JToken container, JToken value)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JsonPath.ScanFilter.<ExecuteFilter>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Program.Main() :line 34
```

would be great to get some directions since i am spinning my head here.

michel

Answer (score 0):

`SelectTokens` uses lazy evaluation and if you modify the token while enumerating all matches it can break in unexpected ways. A simple fix is to add `ToArray()` to force eager evaluation:

```cs
var JsonPaths = jo.SelectTokens("..$JsonPath").ToArray();
```